# How to replace string in files recursively

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line-interface

I'm developing one application. Some path have to be changed on the whole project. The path are fixed and the files can be edited (it is in ".cshtml" ).

So I think I can use a batch file to change all the "http://localhost.com" to "http://domain.com" for example (I know relative and absolute path, but here I HAVE to make that :-) )

So if you have code that can make that changes in files, it could be marvellous!

To complete my question, here it is the path of files and dir

```
MyApp
MyApp/Views
MyApp/Views/Index/page1.cshtml
MyApp/Views/Index/page2.cshtml
MyApp/Views/Another/page7.cshtml
...
```

Thanks to help me :-)

Comment: We would have helped you had you said `it would be marvellous` but, alas, you said `it could be marvellous`.

Answer (score 6):

Something like this might work as well:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

s=http://localhost.com
r=http://example.com

cd /path/to/MyApp

grep -rl "$s" * | while read f; do
  sed -i "s|$s|$r|g" "$f"
done
```

**Edit:** Or not, since you just switched from [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) to [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file). A batch solution might look like this:

```batch
@echo off

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /r "C:\path\to\MyApp" %%f in (*.chtml) do (
  (for /f "tokens=*" %%l in (%%f) do (
    set "line=%%l"
    echo !line:
  )) >"%%~ff.new"
  del /q "%%~ff"
  ren "%%~ff.new" "%%~nxf"
)
```

Doing this in batch is really, *really* ugly, though (error-prone too), and you'd be far better off using [`sed` for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm), or (better yet) doing it in PowerShell:

```bsh
$s = "http://localhost.com"
$r = "http://example.com"

Get-ChildItem "C:\path\to\MyApp" -Recurse -Filter *.chtml | ForEach-Object {
    (Get-Content $_.FullName) |
        ForEach-Object { $_ -replace [regex]::Escape($s), $r } |
        Set-Content $_.FullName
}
```

Note that `-Filter` only works in PowerShell v3. For earlier versions you have to do it like this:

```bsh
Get-ChildItem "C:\path\to\MyApp" -Recurse | Where-Object {
    -not $_.PSIsContainer -and $_.Extension -eq ".chtml"
} | ForEach-Object {
    (Get-Content $_.FullName) |
        ForEach-Object { $_ -replace [regex]::Escape($s), $r } |
        Set-Content $_.FullName
}
```

Comment: Why would it? Your question was about bash, not about batch-files.

Comment: @clement Updated answer with batch and PowerShell solutions. Can't really recommend using batch for this, though.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
find /MyApp -name "*.cshtml" -type f -exec sed -i 's#http://localhost.com#http://domain.com#g' {} +
```

#### Explanation

- `find /MyApp -name "*.cshtml" -type f` looks for files with `.cshtml` extension in `/MyApp` structure.
- `sed -i 's/IN/OUT/g'` replaces the text IN to OUT in the files.
- hence, `sed -i 's#http://localhost.com#http://domain.com#g'` replaces `http://localhost.com` with `http://domain.com`.
- `exec .... {} +` executes .... within the files found by `find`.

Comment: OP might actually want you to replace `IN` and `OUT` with the actual values.

Comment: +1. I may use `+` instead of `\;`. It behaves similar to `xargs`, so less ``sed` call will be performed.

Comment: @devnull thanks for editing, although I had just done it. I rollback your edition!

Comment: I wasn't aware of that, @TrueY. I just tested it with `time` and it took half the time with your option. Thanks!

Comment: @fedorqui: You are most welcome! Nice solution! Anyway the `option` is not mine... It belongs to `find`. ;)

Comment: @fedorqui : Beautiful ! I Can put it in a .bat file? it doesn't look to run correctly :-/

Comment: @clement I am not familiar with .bat files, but as far as I know they are windows related. As my solution is *NIX way, you may look for an interpreter of this code in Windows environment.

Comment: no way, i have to integrate it to a .net project, it must be windows compatible, without add-ons :-/